# I'm making a chat app using Android. I cannot connect to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

IT says 'Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync.'

Below is my build.gradle module.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mchat"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Android studio is updated and you are using Gradle 4.1 or higher.
Also, I couldn't see google services in your dependencies:
`com.google.gms.google-services`

I suggest double-checking the steps in the documentation to make sure you have implemented firebase correctly.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add-config-file

In some situations, you may have a corrupted cached build and it may require deleting the `.gradle/caches` directory. It holds the Gradle build cache and if you have errors about build-cache, you can safely delete it to do a clean build.

Additionally [--no-build-cache](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html#sec:build_cache_enable) option will run Gradle without the build cache.